# PHP AJAX - Can an <input> element have "action" just like how a <form> does?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Forms have an `action` attribute to specify where (for example a `.php` file) to post to. Do `<input>` elements have the `action` attribute?

1. The answer is most likely no. But I wish to know what concept am I getting wrong here?
2. Is there a equivalent of `action` for `<input>`?
3. The reason I am asking this is that I have a few checkboxes, and I wish to use AJAX to fire something to a PHP file, such that a `div` changes when the checkboxes are ticked (I don't want a whole page reload). How should I go about doing this?

I am still drafting the code at this stage, but an example can be seen [here](http://www.courts.com.sg/buy-fans-online-1955.html).

Appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: There's no `action` attribute for inputs. However, you can call the AJAX on `click/checked` event. Please share your code and explain clearly what you want to achieve here.

Comment: use `.load()` on checkbox change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments it really sounds like you want something to be sent when any number of checkboxes might be changed.

Add an event handler to all of them, serialize() the form and post it whenever any one of them changes

```
var $form =$('#myForm'); 
$form.find(':checkbox').change(function(){
     var formData = $form.serialize();
     $.post('/someFile.php', formData, function(response){
         // do something with response
     }).fail(function(){
         alert("Oops something bad happened');
     });
});
```

Comment: @charlietfI Looks really promising! Just one question, say I post to someFile.php, does that make the php page that you are on reload? Or does only one sector of the page reload?

Comment: that's totally up to you. Where I have noted do something with response that response could be html or it could be data to update something in the page . A lot of uses for ajax

Comment: And when it's html returned , most of the time is not a full page...just parts

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery AJAX Methods:

AJAX is the art of exchanging data with a server, and update parts of a web page - without reloading the whole page.

EX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    // You can call ajax on any event of html element like checkbox checked, dropdown changed
        $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('change', '#checkboxid', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#container').load('pages/somephpfile.php');
    }

});
```

Use `.load()` on change of checkbox

1. you cant set which php file to load based on the checkbox status.

Also try

```
$(document).on('change', '#checkboxid', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'somephp.php',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#container').html(data) //load the data from somephp.php here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wouldn't make sense to make same request with no data for both checkbox states

Comment: @charlietfl is this what you mean?

Comment: still think this is a weak example that doesn't show use of `this` or being able to send anything specific related to that checkbox to server

Comment: @charlietfl im sorry i didnt get that part with server? i only read `such that the a div changes when the checkboxes are ticked`

Comment: Read question   *"for example a .php file to post to"* ... to me that usually means something specific with that element

Comment: Hi @charlietfl if you see the example I gave as reference, you can check the boxes and still able to check other boxes/uncheck that box. That works as a search criteria narrowing by serializing a form (my guess) and passing values to a PHP file. That much I know, but I want a direction of how AJAX works with PHP to realize that.

Comment: @iWillGetBetter yes...there is a jQuery method `serialize()` that does a whole form and you would use `$.ajax` as other answer does or `$.post()` or depending on what you need in response could possibly be load() like this answer

Comment: @iWillGetBetter and you might be right back to using the form action aslo doing that. Your question really should  have been how can I submit a form when I check a checkbox

Comment: @charlietfl I see, are you suggesting that the checkboxes search in the example most probably used a form submission method with AJAX?

Comment: @iWillGetBetter in the second example you can do what you want you can return text , json or html from that page then manipulate it in success according to your need